# I can't invite a friend to play in Starcraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

How does one invite specific people to play 1v1 in Starcraft 2?

Acccording to [this note](http://www.ehow.com/how_8340250_invite-friend-play-starcraft-2.html)
I tried the following but failed:

1. Add the guy to friends.
2. Right-click the name of the friend you want to invite in your friends list on the side of the multiplayer lobby. Click "Invite to Party."

But then I can't do anything.
I don't see "Multiplayer" on the top left part of the screen and
I can't add any people when I have created a custom game (the friends are displayed online, but inactive).

P.S. I have SC2-Heart of the swarm.

Comment: There is not enough information here, please elaborate. Do you see a "multiplayer" button while you are alone, and it goes away when you party up? What do you friends see when you invite them?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the guy to friends.
2. Right-click the name of the friend you want to invite in your friends list on the side of the multiplayer lobby. Click "Invite to Party."
3. Click "MATCHMAKING"
4. Click the appropriate button for what game you want to play, either 2vs2, or 2vsA.I., or what have you.